# SQL Server Management Studio On Update Cascade

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, relational-database, cascade

I am working on a simple database where I would want to have a one is to many relationship, I've created a foreign key which has on an `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, based from my understanding of `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, if my Primary gets incremented the Foreign key in the other table that references it will also get incremented/ have the value of the Primary in the other table . but the problem is as I insert data in my Parent table, the foreign Key in the other table did not get the value of the Primary on my parent table why is it like that? How would my foreign key have the value of the key that is related to it? here's a screenshot for you guys to easiy understand [image]

As you can see the `P_ID` in the orders table doesn't have a value even though it is linked to the `P_ID` in the People table

The Expected Result will be that in the Orders table the value of `P_ID` would be equivalent to P_ID of people table, where I inserted my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but the problem is as I insert data in my Parent table.

You wont get any action on insert, only `on update`.

If you have people number 1 and an order to people number one, if you change it to number 2, the order will be changed to 2.

You may want a trigger. tell us more what's the expected result

EDIT:

trigger example:

```
create trigger InsertRecordOnOrder
on People
after insert
as
begin
    insert into Orders
    select * from INSERTED
end
```

Comment: My expected result would be that in the screenshot above, the P_Id in the Order table will have 1 as its value

Comment: @KyelJmD just echoing what Diego said, it sounds like you may want a trigger that fires on insert.

Comment: that's not the objective of a foreign key, specially with ON UPDATE constraint. You should leave your foreign key (without the ON UPDATE, because I dont think you need it) and create a trigger INSTEAD OF INSERT on the Peoples table so every time you insert a person it will automatically insert a order to it

Comment: sorry, the trigger is not INSTEAD OF, is AFTER

Comment: @Diego can you give me a sample of "AFTER INSERT" ?

Comment: "On update" is your cascading definition that I think you don't need.

Comment: About the trigger, I edited my answer. It will fire every time a record is inserted on the People table. Then you can insert a record on the Orders table. You will have to edit the insert statement to insert only the columns you need. All of them will be available on the INSERTED table. Just do INSERTED.COLUMN_NAME

Comment: is that query also applicable in LINQ To mySQL?

Comment: that's a sql server trigger. Not sure the syntax in mySQL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7700/discussion-between-diego-and-kyeljmd)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you misunderstand ON UPDATE CASCADE. Please reference the following link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx